# Producer-Consumer in Java - Multiple Consumers

Tags: java, producer-consumer

I have a producer-consumer model in Java with multiple consumers. I am passing an object between producers and consumers that has a variable, let's call it "name".

Now, this name can be A, B, or C. If the value is A, one consumer will take it off the queue and do something with it. If the value is B, a different consumer will take it off the same queue and do something else. If the value is C, a third consumer does the same.

My question is how to implement this. My current theory is the following (in pseudocode):

```
// This is code for each consumer
pull item off the queue
check if item.name is right for this consumer (A, B, or C)
if so, send it to consume()
else, put it back on the queue
```

Would something like this work, or would it wreak havoc on my thread synchronization? If it wouldn't work, what model should I use to implement this?

Comment: I don't see a reason for multiple consumers here. Since it is only three cases why not have one general consumer deal with it?

Comment: Sounds like you really need message driven beans and topics.

Comment: Are you writing everything from scratch? How about use JMS API ?

Comment: @Sebastian Multiple consumers is mandated by the assignment.

Comment: @duffymo Could you explain a little about them?

Comment: @gerrytan I have most of the code written already, but I can't figure out how to differentiate between consumers.

Comment: JMS, topics, queues, publish/subscribe - it's far more than an SO answer.  Better do some research and come back.

Comment: Assuming all consumer type implement a Consumer interface, add a method `getName()` so you can differentiate them. Other approach is you use `instanceof` to compare the runtime instance of each Consumer subclass

Comment: you could just have each consume peek at the queue or roll up a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to define message headers when the message is published.  Then you can have multiple consumers, each with unique MessageSelectors which look for the specific message header.  This way, only the correct consumer gets the message and you don't have to worry about reposting the message if an incorrect consumer gets the message (which is very inefficient and would not be nice on a loaded system with lots of messages working their way through the system).

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/1_3_1-fcs/doc/prog_model.html